# Create new variable based on condition from one column dplyr data table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, data-manipulation

Sample data:

```
Group <- c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c")    
value_1 <- c(1.10, 2.5, 1.7, 0.99, 1.50, 1.65, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5)
value_2 <- c(0.03, 1.3, 3.5, 0.02, 4.3, 1.2, 1.4, 1.4, 3.7)
new_variable_1 <- c(1,0,1, 1,1,0, 0,0,1)    
df <- data.frame(Group, value_1, value_2, new_variable_1)
```

The output is `new_variable_1`. I want to create a `new_variable_1` based on following criteria; **I am seeking 2 solutions.**

Basic idea:

> lookup the max value in `value_2` by group and create dummy variable based on values in `value_1`.

#### solution 1 Logic:

1. Find `max(value_2)` by group. E.g., the max value in `value_2` for group `a` is `3.5`
2. Find the corresponding `value_1` by group. E.g., `value_1` is `1.7`  in group `a`
3. create `new_variable_1` by group that is `1` if `value_1` is less than the corresponding value in the above step. E.g., for group `a`, `value_1 <= 1.7` should show `1` &  `value_1 > 1.7` should show `0`.

#### solution 2 Logic:

Same as above, but increase the threshold value from step 2 by 10%.

1. the max value in `value_2` for group `a` is `3.5`
2. it then corresponds to value `1.7` `value_1` in group `a`
3. Increase the value by `10%`. For group a `10%` in increase would be `1.87`.
4. Create `new_variable_1`: for group a, `value_1 <= 1.87` should show `1` &  `value_1 > 1.87` should show `0`.

R, `dplyr`, `data.table` and most efficient R codes are welcome.

It's a large dataset so groups may have different length and `Inf` or `NA` may exist in `value_2`.

Comment: Do you mean `data.table` or a `datatable`?

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to better formulate the question. It is easier to copy and paste the desired output. It is more visually "appealing" or easier to follow(in my opinion).

Answer (score 1):

We could try. I've used names starting with "New" to make it easier to follow.

Solution 1(Thanks to @Gregor):

```
library(dplyr)


 df %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>%  
  mutate(New_variable_1 = ifelse(value_1 <= value_1[which.max(value_2)], 1, 0))
```

Solution 2: Thanks to @Gregor

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>%  
  mutate(New_variable_1 = ifelse(value_1 <= value_1[which.max(value_2)], 1, 0),
         NewVar1=value_1[which.max(value_2)]*1.1)
```

Comment: Thanks Nelson. I need to tackle all groups and not just group a. your code is only correct for group "a" but not for other groups.

Comment: Well you don't say what happens to other groups so I assumed they take maximum values of `value_1`. @JonDongen

Comment: new_variable_1 is the correct output. Apologies for not being clear.

Comment: Please check the output and see if it matches your expected values. I see one difference at row 6. @JonDongen

Comment: Thanks Jon for your comments. Yes, code should tackle operation by group. In each group we select the max(value_2) and its corresponding value in (value_1). We then use the (value_1) by group to create the indicator variable.

Comment: Lets look at group "b".

Comment: The max(value_2) in group "b" is: 4.3    The corresponding value for group "b" (value_1) is: 1.5  so for group "b" solution 1: anything <= 1.5 is 1 and > 1.5 is 0

Comment: Please simply tweak these values as required. You can use `%in%` to define groups and ranges.

Comment: @NelsonGon I understand now, `1.7` is used because it is the `value_1`  value in the same row as `max(value_2)` for group 'a'`. (That's what OP means by "corresponding".) Similarly 1.5 for group 'b' because it is in row 5, which has the max `value_2` for group 'b', etc.

Comment: Nelson, please can you tweak the code by group. if i knew how to then I wouldn't have posted the question.

Comment: Thanks @Gregor for the insight. Let's see how to tweak it.

Comment: I edited the question---I think it's clearer. You don't need an `ifelse` for the `max`, it's always the max of `value_2`. I think something like `New_variable_1 = ifelse(value_1 <= value_1[which.max(value_2)], 1, 0)` is what is needed (for solution 1... for solution 2 multiply by 1.1).

Comment: Edited. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I think it's the threshold that needs multiplication, not the result. `1.1 * value_1[which.max(value_2)`

Comment: Ah, OP means this value by "the value". Got it, thanks again! @Gregor